# Plane determined by point and normal vector (equivalence proof)

Tags: linear-algebra

We know that given a normal vector $\mathbf{n}$ and a point $\mathbf{a},$ a plane is uniquely determined. (Say we are in $\mathbb{R^3}.$) Now, given an arbitrary point $\mathbf{b}$ on the plane, we know that

$$(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a})\cdot \mathbf{n}=0.\tag{1}$$

My question is that we showed if a point is on the plane, it has to satisfy $(1)$. But we didn't show if a point satisfy $(1)$, it is on the plane. How do you show it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to show that $(b-a).n=0$ is equivalent to any way (you agree) of describing a plane, for example, using your notation, suppose that $b$ satisfy this equation, then:

$$ (b-a).n=0 $$
$$ b.n - a.n = 0 $$
$$ b.n = a.n$$
$$ ax+by+cz = d$$

for $b = (x,y,z)$, $n=(a,b,c)$ and $d = a.n$

Note that $n$ and $d$ are fixed.

Comment: But what does this tell us? I mean why does $ax+by+cz=d$ showed $b$ is on the plane?